# EF eager loading from stored procedure

Tags: entity-framework

I've created a stored procedure to manage searching on my application. The stored procedure returns a collection of "cases".

When displaying my search results I reference a property of each "case" that is a linked table in the database. At the moment lazy loading makes the EF framework load the linked property for each "case".

Mini profiler shows this as duplicate trips to the database one for each object returned (possibly 200 objects) is there a way to say load all the linked properties in one go rather than leaving lazy loading to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use .Include() directly but once you get the results from the stored procs you can run a single Linq query to get all the related results - something like:

```
var relatedReults = ctx.RelatedResults.Where(r => ids.Contains(r.Id)).ToArray();
```

where ids is an array of ids you build based on the results returned by your stored proc. EF should be able to fix up the relations so after running the query you should be able to access related entities without sending additional queries.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion and it loads a list of all the linked objects. However when i go back to the search results and reference a linked property EF is still doing a trip to the database.  Do i need to tell EF to cache the objects?